# efficient generation of numbers with Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I wish to generate more than 10^8 random numbers with Boost. They must be normally distributed with standard deviation 1 and mean 0. Here is my MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <time.h>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef boost::mt19937                     ENG;
    typedef boost::normal_distribution<double> DIST;
    typedef boost::variate_generator<ENG,DIST> GEN;

    ENG  eng;
    DIST dist(0,1);
    GEN  gen(eng,dist);

    gen.engine().seed(time(0));

    vector<double> nums;

    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        nums.push_back(gen());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 questions in this regard:

1. Is the approach I am using to seed the engine correct? Or do I need to seed it before *each* number?
2. Is my method efficient? Or is there a better way?

**EDIT** Note that there is no bottleneck in the code as such. I am just wondering if my approach is correct from a professional point of view

I should say that the numbers (all of them) have to be scaled by a proper constant afterwards. My plan is to use a for-loop for this.

Best,
Niles.

Comment: 1) Yes, you should only seed the generator once. 2) Are you sure this is the bootleneck in your code?

Comment: There is no bottleneck currently. I am wondering if my approach is correct from a professional viewpoint.

Comment: I would never store the numbers, but generate them on the fly after abstracting the generator away behind a lightweight interface. Your code right now isn't wrong, but if you want to run this in a batch farm you might need a more unique seed (not one that just depends on the current time). This all depends on what exactly you need.

Comment: Agree with honk it's not normal practise to store the results but just use them 'on the fly' and throw them away. By using the same seed you can reproduce the same numbers for verification testing etc. It's also good to make a choice of RNGs available, some of which generate more outputs per step than others, so you can end up with some sort of abstract producer class with an interface independent of the actual generator used. Best book on this subject: Monte Carlo Methods in Finance by Peter Jaeckel

Comment: Don't "scale by a constant factor afterwards". That's the job of `boost::normal_distribution`.